# javascript function shows previous result

Tags: javascript, html

When i saved my javascript file in which function like that:

```
function deletefolder1(ID)
{

    document.write("hello world");
}
and call from here:
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='deletefolder1($folderID) class='deletefolder'>Delete a folder</a>
```

it works fine:

but when i replace function appsolutely same like that:

```
function deletefolder1(ID)
{
    $.post("modules_user/module_user/scripts/addtofolder.php",{folderID:ID});
}
```

it again shows result:
HELLO WORLD

what a crap, i don't know what to do, i think my script crack some where or computer memory didn't replace with the new content.

Comment: you did something wrong obviously. have you deleted the old function, clear you browser's cache?

Comment: Thanks Alaxandar and usman. Yea it was cache problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the browser cache or press Ctrl + F5 to get latest javascript in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this kind of error time and again (most probably in IE), You should request your js file in this way:

First generate random value from your server.

If you are using PHP you can write your code as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js?rand=<?php echo $random;?>"> 
</script>
```